# How should I simplify this $\tan^{-1}$ expression?

Tags: calculus

Integral question I have to integrate this function 
$$I = \int_0^4\frac{20x-5x^2}{x^2+9} \mathrm{d}x$$
obtaining 
$$20\ln(5/3) + 15\tan^{-1}(4/3) -20.$$
However, my calculator, even after somehow simplifying it a bit, gives this: 
$$\frac{40\ln(5/3) -30\tan^{-1}(3/4) +15\pi -40}{2}$$

As you can see there is something wrong with arctan integration, can anybody help or know how to simplify this with some identity?

I am asking this because it is one of the questions in the practise exam, and in the exam i will have to use this calculator, no others allowed, so if a question like this comes up, i will get stuck..

Comment: Are you sure you have both $\tan^{-1}(3/4)$ and $\tan^{-1}(4/3)$?  This isn't a typo?

Comment: $$\tan^{-1}\frac{3}{4} + \tan^{-1}\frac{4}{3} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Do you know how that identity is called? :) Or should this be sort of obvious?

Comment: It is a trivial consequence of $\cot x = \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers are the same when you notice that, for $x\gt0$,
$$
\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1x\right)=\frac\pi2-\tan^{-1}(x)
$$

---

Note that
$$
\tan^{-1}\left(\frac ba\right)=B\quad\text{and}\quad\tan^{-1}\left(\frac ab\right)=A
$$
and
$$
A+B=\frac\pi2
$$
$\hspace{3.4cm}$[image]

---

If you want to use trigonometric identities,
$$
\begin{align}
\tan\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)
&=\frac{\sin\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)}{\cos\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)}\\
&=\frac{\sin\left(\frac\pi2\right)\cos(x)-\cos\left(\frac\pi2\right)\sin(x)}{\cos\left(\frac\pi2\right)\cos(x)+\sin\left(\frac\pi2\right)\sin(x)}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\\[12pt]
&=\frac1{\tan(x)}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @robjohn:  Caught my typo a second after adding the comment.  Deleted subsequently.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this identity. But I am still a bit confused of how it is true...

Comment: @Deo: consider a right triangle. The non-right angles add up to $\frac\pi2$. If you compute the tangents of the non-right angles you are dividing the non-hypontenuse sides in opposite orders.

Comment: Ok so tan(x) = 3/4
tan(pi/2 - x) = 4/3
is that it?
Is there a trigonometric identity way to prove it?

Comment: @Deo: I've added a diagram

Answer (score 0):

By first simplifying the fraction, we get that $$\frac{40\ln(5/3) -30\tan^{-1}(3/4) +15\pi -40}{2} = 20\ln(5/3) -15\tan^{-1}(3/4) +\frac{15}{2}\pi -20$$

Subtracting $20\ln(5/3) + 15\tan^{-1}(4/3) -20$ from it, we get $$(20\ln(5/3) -15\tan^{-1}(3/4) +\frac{15}{2}\pi -20) - (20\ln(5/3) + 15\tan^{-1}(4/3) -20)$$
$$ = \frac{15}{2}\pi - 15\tan^{-1}(4/3) -15\tan^{-1}(3/4) = 15 \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1} (4/3) - \tan^{-1} (3/4)\right)$$

Here we bring in the definition of tangent. Given a right triangle $ABC$ with $C$ being the right angle, $$\tan \angle ABC = \frac{AC}{BC}$$ From this, we get that $$\angle ABC = \tan^{-1} \frac{AC}{BC}$$

Now, we take a $3-4-5$ triangle and note that the two inverse tangents are the two angles that are not $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}$. Because the angles of a triangle add up to $\pi$, we note that they sum to $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}$. Therefore, $$15 \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1} (4/3) - \tan^{-1} (3/4)\right) = 15 \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 0$$

Q.E.D.